# How can I build a function for Fibonacci numbers 1:42

Tags: r

I tried to build the function but I only am able to build a sequence not a function. Could someone give me some help with building a fib function.

I expected a function but I wasn't able to build it and the sequence was not what I wanted.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a function that lets you determine how many Fibonacci numbers you want to get:

```
# define number of numbers in Fibonacci sequence (with edits suggested by [@Dirk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/143305/dirk-eddelbuettel))

fib <- function(n) {
  x = numeric(n)
  x[1:3] = c(0,1,1)
  for(i in 4:n) x[i] = x[i-1] + x[i-2]
  x
}
```

Say, you want to see the first 10 Fibonacci numbers:

```
fib(10)
[1]  0  1  1  2  3  5  8 13 21 34
```

Comment: I need 1,2,3,5 so on not 0 1 1 2

Comment: @leon the Fibonacci sequence starts 1, 1, 2, 3, 5. If you don't want the leading 0, return x[-1] from the function instead of x

Comment: Take a look at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number